# Trim parts against parts in assembly level solidworks

Tags: solidworks

In solidworks , is it possible to trim a part against another part in assembly level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The cut must be added to the feature tree of the part to be trimmed, but the location of the body remains defined within the assembly.

I wouldn't usually recommend this as best practice, however, since there are a lot of interlinking references. (Suggesting an alternate referencing structure is outside the scope of this question, however).

1. In the assembly, click Edit Component for the part to be cut
2. Insert - Feature - Cavity
3. Select the part that you wish to do the cutting with.
4. Hide the cutting tool if necessary. You can't suppress or delete it, as the cavity feature is referencing it.

[image: Assembly Boolean Demo]

Comment: If the part you substracted (the cylinder) was a tube, would it be possible to substract the hollow interior from the cube too? So you could be left with the same cut you showed in your Gif

Comment: Not directly using the same tool shown, but it would be easy to create a new body that references the outer form of the tube only and is solid, then use that as the cut tool.