# Is it possible to compute cutting of wood bar in Solidworks automatically?

Tags: solidworks, cutting

I drew two bar parts, horizontal and vertical, then composed into single assembly. Each bar was duplicated.

The I wished to model diagonal bar and created new part just inside of an assembly. I was able to build appropriate plane and extruded the bar up to angles:

[image]

Now, how can I model cuts?

Comment: You want the cavity tool - there's an answer elsewhere on this site I did a while ago - I'll try to find the link

Comment: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32776/trim-parts-against-parts-in-assembly-level-solidworks/32781?r=SearchResults#32781

Comment: Or perhaps better define planes in the diagonal part based on the positions of the other components and then use them as cut tools (cut with surface command)